# Custom Flutter Map Marker with Text

Tags: flutter, text, marker, fluttermap

For some time now i have been trying to set markers with the flutter map which not only display an icon but also contain text. I know it would work with the google map but i'm trying to get by with the flutter map.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your icon with a column and add your text with it. Like this:

```dart
         Marker(point: LatLng(currLatitude,currLongitude), builder: (context) =>
              Container(child: Column(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.location_on,size: 40,),
                  Text("data",style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 12),)
                  ],
                ),
              )
          )
```